# Not able to fetch Image

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I am trying to get image but i am getting error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

**TopBar.jsx**

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Context } from "../../context/Context";
import "./topbar.css"

const Topbar = () => {
    const { user, dispatch } = useContext(Context);
    const PF = "http://localhost:5000/images/";

    const handleLogout = () => {
        dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
    };

    return (
        <div className="top">
            <div className="topLeft">
                <i className="topIcon fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
                <i className="topIcon fab fa-twitter-square"></i>
                <i className="topIcon fab fa-instagram-square"></i>
            </div>
            <div className="topCenter">
                <ul className="topList">
                    <li className="topListItem">
                        <Link className="link" to="/">
                            HOME
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="topListItem">
                        <Link className="link" to="/">
                            CONTACT
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="topListItem">
                        <Link className="link" to="/write">
                            WRITE
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="topListItem" onClick={handleLogout}>
                        {user && "LOGOUT"}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="topRight">
                {user ? (
                    <Link to="/settings">
                        <img className="topImg" src={PF + user.profilePic} alt="" />
                    </Link>
                ) : (
                    <ul className="topList">
                        <li className="topListItem">
                            <Link className="link" to="/login">
                                LOGIN
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="topListItem">
                            <Link className="link" to="/register">
                                REGISTER
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Topbar;
```

**User.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    profilePic: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
    },
},
{
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const userRoute = require("./routes/users");
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");
const categoryRoute = require("./routes/categories");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

dotenv.config();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/images")));

mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true
    })
    .then(console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "images");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, req.body.name);
    },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json("File has been uploaded");
});

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoute);
app.use("/api/categories", categoryRoute);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Backend is running on localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

I'm a beginner in this and i am having a very hard time wrapping this concept around my head. if there's any other way, please provide the link to refer.

[github link](https://github.com/JavaKaran/BlogApplication)

Comment: This is because you don't have any `/images` route. You need to add a `app.get("/images/:id")` */:id* for user pic id.

Answer (score 1):

Try entering in the image url `http://localhost:5000/images/someRandomPic` in the address bar. If it doesn't showup then the image either isn't in the `/images` directory or the server assets aren't reachable (perhaps wrong port?)

If you do get back an image in the browser, then its likely an issue with `user.profilePic` not being what you expect when you're expecting it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to serve your static files from express:

try Adding this:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

(public is the folder where your images and everything (assets) reside)

More infos here: http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html